# Apache - PHP for local development

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I am setting-up a development environment with Ubuntu, Apache2 and PHP. I am actually serving my project in `/var/www/html/myproject/`, but when I open my project source from PHPStorm to edit, it's not possible because denied permission, how can I edit my project source and serve it in local environment?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/?

Comment: @NickJ No problem if I change permission for `www` ?

Comment: change ownership of the files/directories so YOUR account can access them, as well as apache's account.

Comment: @MarcB a `simple sudo chown user /var/www/myproject/` will do the trick?

Comment: @Gocht If I remember correctly you will want the owner to be you and the group to be the same group that the webserver uses. Then I think you just need to add your user to that group.

Comment: no, then you'll lock the webserver out of it.

Comment: @MarcB So, What do you recommend?

Comment: you can either make the dirs/files globally read/write, e.g. mode 666. if that's a no-go because it's too permissive, then either put your account into the www-data group, or create a NEW group with the apache and your own accounts in it, and chgrp the files/dirs to that group

Comment: @MarcB Thanks! If you put this below as an answer with a little bit more explanation, I'll be glad to accept it.